# Age of Sigmar: if Ghouls are delusional, how come their "titles" are realistic?

Tags: age-of-sigmar

In the newest background for *Warhammer: Age of Sigmar*'s brand of Ghouls, now called "The Flesh-Eater Courts", the Ghouls are deranged humanoids led by a vampire-like Ghoul King who projects a magical kind of insanity into his minions, making them believe they aren't monsters but normal humans in fine livery and living in noble courts, complete with king, royal family, courtiers, servants, knights and foot soldiers. It's important to note the Ghoul King himself shares this delusion, as shown in this [short story](https://malignportents.com/story/time-of-plenty/):

> As High King Atheldade gestured grandly at the banquet laid out before him, the silken ribbons of his regalia billowed in the scented air. He smiled at his reflection in his nearby seeing-glass, then looked upon his gathered court, as proud and benevolent as a father watching his children playing in a meadow.
>
> [...]
>
> There were hundreds of his kith gathered, gossiping and laughing lightly with excitement. Every man, woman and child was hale and hearty, with rosy cheeks and gleaming eyes.

An alternate paragraph in the same story shows they are not in a castle but in a mountain, and they are all horrible and disgusting Ghouls feasting on corpses.

However, their official rulebook (Battletome: Flesh-Eater Courts) later describes the many roles and positions in a Flesh-Eater Court, which puzzlingly include:

- The "Giblet Prince", or heir apparent.
- The "Offal Queen".
- "Lord Marrowbroth".
- The "Marquis Retchbile".

etc.

How can this be? If the Ghouls are deluded into thinking they are normal humans in a normal court, they cannot use Ghoulish names. In fact, contrast these names with the "High King Atheldade" earlier, or another from the Battletome, who styles himself "Lord Pergrin" and fancies himself a mighty knight fighting against bestial creatures. Note that in the fragments from the Ghouls' point of view, the names are actually nicer! (i.e. it's not a case of Ghouls mistakenly thinking "Retchbile" is a nice name, but instead the names mentioned are actually nicer, like "Lord Pergrin").

It seems these Ghoulish titles were given from the perspective of someone who is aware these are Ghouls, which means it cannot be the Ghouls themselves! Is there any indication who chose these names?

Comment: If they are deluded enough to see fine clothes, smell fine perfumes, and taste fine food when in reality it's all rotten, what's stopping them from hearing fine names when the names are also rotten?

Comment: They do not even need to hear different, "fine" names, they simply need to perceive those names as perfectly fine.

Comment: @Giter & Florian: all valid points! So are you saying when "High King Atheldade" tries to name things -- for example, his own name, "High King Atheldade" -- he actually says "Grim King Rottingstuff" but he hears himself saying the finer name? So that he tries to say something nice, but says something horrible? And the Battletome tells us the names he actually says as they sound to human ears? Sounds... convoluted, but it works. For this to work, the Ghouls need to be saying "Retchbile" when they try to say "Williams", like a total disconnect between brain and mouth :)

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz But how does this theory explain names like "High King Atheldade", "Lord Pergrin", etc?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz - Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe Florian is attempting to take the theory to its base. You state 3 of the 5 senses in your question that the Ghouls have been able to warp to their own desires... one could argue 4 given that they are touching the rancid meat while eating it and I'm sure the king is wearing "silk"... This only leaves what they hear - which your question is about. Because the Ghouls have duped 4 of their 5 senses from terrible to terrific already it is possible that : what they say is terrible, what they hear is terrible, BUT their minds make it terrific.

Comment: @Odin1806 Now I understand! Yes, it makes sense. So when the linked short story says "High King Atheldade", the writer -- who is not a Ghoul -- is doing one final translation for the reader, explaining to us how a name like "Low King Putrid" would be interpreted inside the Ghoul King's brain? But the Ghouls never actually use names like "High King Atheldade"?

Comment: @AndresF. -Maybe?! Without having read these passages in their entirety myself it is hard to know. That is definitely how your edit makes it sound! Otherwise it is purely the perception of the king himself (because he is projecting all of this onto all the other ghouls) and the author is attempting to find the balance between the reality and delusion in tandem to describe to the reader. While everything around the king is disgusting his self imposed delusion forces him to perceive everything as beautiful. Similar to how eating snails sound disgusting to some and it sounds delicious to others..

Comment: Well, there are always terms that are "correct" for Outsiders and Ghouls alike: King, for example. Both would perceive that as actually "correct". The ghouls don't seem to call their king, let's say "First Corpse Eater" instead of "king" or something like that. So, the theory would be, that they simply perceive everything as "correct" that is used in the appropriate context. If, let's say, the king would introduce the title of "First Vomiter", chances are that his people would consider that an honor - same as if the king introduced the "First knight" title. Same with names.